# Systemd: How to load LUKS passphrase from USB, falling back to keyboard?

Tags: ubuntu, systemd

I want to set up a headless GNU/Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) PC with full disk encryption, with the ability to unlock the disks either with a USB drive, or by entering a passphrase by keyboard.  My starting point is a fresh install using the basic full disk encryption option in the installer, which manages everything besides /boot as a LUKS-encrypted logical volume group and gives me the keyboard option.

It would be ideal to me if I could simply have a small USB stick
containing a passphrase that will unlock the disks. Not only would that
be handy for servers (where you could leave the USB stick in the
server - the goal is to be able to return broken harddisks without
having to worry about confidential data), it would also be great for
my laptop: Insert the USB stick when booting and remove it after
unlocking the cryptodisk. And if the USB-disk breaks, use the keyboard.

How can this be done in a way that will work on a system that runs `systemd`?

(And if this question seems familiar it is due to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23451824/363028 - which solved the problem, but is incompatible with systemd.)

**Background**

On my non-systemd system I use this patch https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/tree/master/decrypt-root-with-usb

It searches the root dir of all
devices for the file 'cryptkey.txt' and try decrypting with each line
as a key. If that fails: Revert to typing in the pass phrase.

And it works exactly how I want, but systemd breaks this, so I cannot use this (at least not directly).

Comment: From reading the question, you know what you're talking about, so I don't think I have anything to add. One thing got me curious though - why did you want this solved by systemd? How would you want to use it to help with this problem? I'm not sure how you would see this being automated -- would be interesting to find out.

Comment: seems too obvious but would this be of use to you? https://discussion.fedoraproject.org/t/full-disk-encryption-how-can-i-automatically-unlock-via-a-usb-key-on-silverblue/11407 (the method, not the specifics)

Comment: @Pedro I have updated the question: I do not need `systemd` to do the work. I just need a solution that works on a system running `systemd`.

Comment: @Pedro The discussion on Fedora seems to have no fall back to keyboard.

Comment: Checkout dracut and clevis it should have what you need or at least a good place to put the scritps that you'd need to use. Has fallback keyboard examples as well.

https://github.com/latchset/clevis

Comment: I think I understand now. You can decrypt from the USB stick, and boot, but if the USB stick isn't there you're not asked for a passphrase. If taht is the case, I think you'll need to tinker with the key handling scripts referenced under the crypttab and add them to the initramfs. Ubuntu should use the same set of decrypt_* scripts you'd find on a debian system. Also the that fedora page does mention a passphrase fallback if USB fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Digging deeper into the actual boot process I do not even need `systemd`, but can use my patch with few changes. So here is the updated version for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:
https://gitlab.com/ole.tange/tangetools/-/tree/master/decrypt-root-with-usb/ubuntu-20.04